# How to submit the same form multiple times all at once with the same submit button

Tags: django

I am still exploring and learning python and django, and I'm also working on some projects as well.
I am currently building a student management system, but I failed to continue since I can't make my duplicate form accept marks input of multiple students.

Here's my code!
In my forms.py

```
class AdvancedMathsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ResultsALevel
        fields = ('student_name', 'advanced_maths_1', 'advanced_maths_2',)
```

Then here's my models.py

```
class ResultsALevel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(AdvancedStudents, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a_level_student')
    title = models.OneToOneField(ExamTitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    accountancy = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    advanced_maths_1 = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    advanced_maths_2 = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here's my views.py

```
class MarksEntryView(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def form_5_entry_maths_view(self, request):
        student_first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        student_middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
        student_last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        maths_1_marks = request.POST.get('maths_paper_1')
        maths_2_marks = request.POST.get('maths_paper_2')
        print(f"{student_first_name}, {maths_1_marks}, {maths_2_marks}")
        for student_first in student_first_name:
            print(student_first)
        current_teacher = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
        logged_school = current_teacher.school_number
        students_involved = User.objects.get(school_number=logged_school).teacher.all()
        data_taken = ResultsALevel(student_name=None, advanced_maths_1=maths_1_marks, 
        advanced_maths_2=maths_2_marks)
        data_taken.save()
        context = {'students': students_involved}
        return render(request, 'analyzer/marks_entry/marks_entry_page.html', context)
```

And here's my html file

```
   {% extends 'analyzer/layouts/base.html' %}

   {% block title %} Page User {% endblock %}

   <!-- Specific Page CSS goes HERE  -->
   {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

   {% block content %}
   {% load static %}

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Form 5 Students</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table class="table tablesorter " id="">
                            <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    First Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Middle Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Last Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Form
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Maths Paper 1
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Maths Paper 2
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for student in students %}
                                {% if student and student.class_studying == 'Form VI' %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{ student.first_name }}">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="middle_name" class="form-control" disabled="" value="{{ student.middle_name }}">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" disabled="" value="{{ student.last_name }}">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="" value="{{ student.class_studying }}">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maths_paper_1">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maths_paper_2">
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary">Save</button>
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% endblock content %}

    <!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement adding multiple objects with Django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128033/how-can-i-implement-adding-multiple-objects-with-django-form)

Comment: NO, I don't think it does, you see what I have is a form that is supposed to store the marks of students who are already registered into the system. So my idea was to fill the marks of all the registered students in one page where all their forms will show up and be submitted at once.  You can also suggest another good way of doing this!

Comment: Well that answer does recommend formsets and that _can_ do what you want. It also recommends ajax (honestly not needed, the formset is enough) which again can do that. So it _does_ answer your question. Read the documentation a bit on [Model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Ok let me go through it and I'll tell you if it works for me!

Comment: It seems to be what I was looking for, but I haven't tried it out yet. So how do I set the extra attribute to be dynamic and according to the number of students available in that class. So that the system only displays the required number of forms

Answer (score 0):

Basically like others mentioned you are looking for [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/).

[Here is a simple tutorial](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) to implementing this in Django as well as the frontend template using a plugin called [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset).
Regarding a question in one of your comments:

> So how do I set the extra attribute to be dynamic and according to the number of students available in that class. So that the system only displays the required number of forms

You have various options within Django itself, like when using `formset_factory()` you can implement attributes like `formset_factory(min_num=X, max_num=X)`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.formset_factory) for reference.

However, if your formset includes an existing property relating to students it might already come up with the desired amount of forms.
To clarify: if you would create a formset to add new students for example, by default you would gain 1 empty form rendered.
But if you would use a formset to to edit a list of students for example, it would render 1 form for each existing student already + an additional empty form (`formset_factory()` has a default attribute setting of `extra=1`).
So if your students already had marks and you would just need an edit list, `formset_factory()` with an attribute of `extra=0` would already get you the number of forms you want.

Also instead you could use jQuery/JS inside the template to adjust the amount of forms. But that's probably not advisable since one of the core ideas of Django is to [separate logic from presentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/misc/design-philosophies/#template-system).

So in your `forms.py` you could add something like this:

```py
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet
class StudentsInClassFormset(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        """
        Adds validation to check that no two items have the same full name,
        and that all items have a first and a last name.
        """
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        first_names = []
        last_names = []
        duplicates = False

        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data:
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

                # Check that no two items have the same combination of first and last name
                if first_names and last_names:
                    if first_name in first_names:
                        if last_name is last_names[first_names.index(first_name)]:
                            duplicates = True
                    first_names.append(first_name)
                    last_names.append(last_name)


                if duplicates:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Auditees must have unique Names.',
                        code='duplicate_auditees'
                    )

                # Check that all items have a first and a last name
                if last_name and not first_name:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'All students must have an first name.',
                        code='missing_first_name'
                    )
                elif first_name and not last_name:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'All students must have a last name.',
                        code='missing_last_name'
                    )
```

Which is a modified class based on the linked tutorial I currently use for a similar formset. Note that all the validation is optional and can be customised to your needs.

You may add following in your view in `views.py`:

```py
my_students_formset = formset_factory(AdvancedMathsForm, formset=StudentsInClassFormset)
```